# Using only author-name for short citation in biblatex-chicago

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biblatex-chicago

How can I tell `biblatex-chicago` to use only the author's name for most short citations, only adding the `shorttitle` when not doing so would cause ambiguity?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[notes]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

A.\footcite[1]{worman}

B.\footcite[213]{doody}

A.\footcite[7]{worman}

\end{document}
```

In this example, I would like `biblatex-chicago` to notice that only one citation has an author whose last name is Worman and therefore to omit the title from footnote 3, printing:

> Worman, 7.

instead of:

> Worman, *Cast of Character*, 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`biblatex` has the test `\ifsingletitle` to detect if a `labelname` has only exactly one title in the bibliography. You can activate it by passing `singletitle=true` as option to `biblatex`.

We then only need to modify the `cite:short` macro to only print the title if `\ifsingletitle` is false. The macro definitions for `biblatex-chicago` are a bit daunting at first, but the only thing that changed are the last lines.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[notes, singletitle]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:short}{%
  \usebibmacro{allshort+firstcite+xref}%
  \ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR%
    \ifentrytype{inreference}\OR%
    \ifentrytype{reference}\OR%
    \ifentrytype{mvreference}}%
  {\ifthenelse{\iffieldequalstr{entrysubtype}{magazine}\AND\NOT%
      \ifentrytype{periodical}}% Simplify .bib creation
    {\ifuseauthor%
      {\ifboolexpr{%
          not test {\iffieldundef{shortjournal}}%
          and
          ((
          test {\ifcitation}%
          and
          togl {cms@citejtabb}%
          )
          or
          (
          test {\ifbibliography}%
          and
          togl {cms@bibjtabb}%
          ))
        }%
        {\printfield[shortjournal]{shortjournal}\newcunit}%
        {\printfield[journaltitle]{journaltitle}\newcunit}}%
      {}}%
    {\ifentrytype{manual}%
      {\printlist{organization}\isdot\newcunit}%
      {}}}%
  {\ifboolexpr{%
      test {\ifciteidem}%
      and
      not test {\ifbibliography}%
      and
      not test {\iffirstonpage}%
      and
      not togl {cms@noidem}%
      and
      not togl {cms@headlessnote}%
    }%
    {\bibstring[\mkibid]{idem\thefield{gender}}%
      \classicpunct}%
    {\iffieldequalstr{authortype}{anon}%
      {\bibleftbracket\printnames{labelname}%
        \bibrightbracket\classicpunct}%
      {\iffieldequalstr{authortype}{anon?}%
        {\bibleftbracket\printnames{labelname}?%
          \bibrightbracket\classicpunct}%
        {\printnames{labelname}%\usebibmacro{choose+labelname}%
          \isdot\classicpunct}}}}%
  \ifsingletitle
    {}
    {\ifboolexpr{%
       togl {cms@allshort}%
       or
       test {\ifbibliography}%
     }%
     {\printtext[bibhyperref]{%
       \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}}%
     {\printtext[cmshyperlink]{%
       \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}}}}%:\thefield{entrytype}?


\begin{document}

A.\footcite[1]{worman}

B.\footcite[213]{doody}

A.\footcite[7]{worman}

\end{document}
```