# Making author-only citations in biblatex-chicago more robust: headlesscite and textcite

Tags: biblatex, citing, biblatex-chicago

A year ago, @moewe [devised a way](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/408913/using-only-author-name-for-short-citation-in-biblatex-chicago) to make `biblatex-chicago` use only the author's last name (no title) when citing a reference whose author only appears in the bibliography as the author of that reference (i.e., only one work by that author is cited).

Since then, I realized that this solution runs into problems with `\headlesscite` and, in footnotes, with `\textcite`. Is there any way to make the output (see below) sensible?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[%
    ibidtracker=true,
    notes, 
    singletitle, 
    short]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:short}{%
  \usebibmacro{allshort+firstcite+xref}%
  \ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR%
    \ifentrytype{inreference}\OR%
    \ifentrytype{reference}\OR%
    \ifentrytype{mvreference}}%
  {\ifthenelse{\iffieldequalstr{entrysubtype}{magazine}\AND\NOT%
      \ifentrytype{periodical}}% Simplify .bib creation
    {\ifuseauthor%
      {\ifboolexpr{%
          not test {\iffieldundef{shortjournal}}%
          and
          ((
          test {\ifcitation}%
          and
          togl {cms@citejtabb}%
          )
          or
          (
          test {\ifbibliography}%
          and
          togl {cms@bibjtabb}%
          ))
        }%
        {\printfield[shortjournal]{shortjournal}\newcunit}%
        {\printfield[journaltitle]{journaltitle}\newcunit}}%
      {}}%
    {\ifentrytype{manual}%
      {\printlist{organization}\isdot\newcunit}%
      {}}}%
  {\ifboolexpr{%
      test {\ifciteidem}%
      and
      not test {\ifbibliography}%
      and
      not test {\iffirstonpage}%
      and
      not togl {cms@noidem}%
      and
      not togl {cms@headlessnote}%
    }%
    {\bibstring[\mkibid]{idem\thefield{gender}}%
      \classicpunct}%
    {\iffieldequalstr{authortype}{anon}%
      {\bibleftbracket\printnames{labelname}%
        \bibrightbracket\classicpunct}%
      {\iffieldequalstr{authortype}{anon?}%
        {\bibleftbracket\printnames{labelname}?%
          \bibrightbracket\classicpunct}%
        {\printnames{labelname}%\usebibmacro{choose+labelname}%
          \isdot\classicpunct}}}}%
  \ifsingletitle
    {}
    {\ifboolexpr{%
       togl {cms@allshort}%
       or
       test {\ifbibliography}%
     }%
     {\printtext[bibhyperref]{%
       \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}}%
     {\printtext[cmshyperlink]{%
       \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}}}}%:\thefield{entrytype}?


\begin{document}


\section{headlesscite and textcite in footnotes}

Headlesscite here: \headlesscite{worman}.

\mancite

In a footnote.\footcite[1]{worman}

\mancite

With textcite.\footnote{\Textcite[1]{worman} says otherwise.}

\mancite

With textcite but no page number.\footnote{\Textcite{worman} says otherwise.}

\section{with ibid issues thrown in}

Repeated citation.\footcite[1]{worman}

Repeated citation with textcite.\footnote{\Textcite[1]{worman} says otherwise.}

Repeated citation with textcite but no page number.\footnote{\Textcite{worman} says otherwise.}

\end{document}
```

## Current output

> **1 headlesscite and textcite in footnotes**
>
> Headlesscite here: .
>
> In a footnote.1
>
> With textcite.2
>
> With textcite but no page number.3
>
> **2 with ibid issues thrown in**
>
> Repeated citation.4
>
> Repeated citation with textcite.5
>
> Repeated citation with textcite but no page number.6

where the footnotes are:

> 1. Worman, 1.
> 2. Worman (, 1) says otherwise.
> 3. Worman () says otherwise.
> 4. Ibid., 1.
> 5. Worman (, 1) says otherwise.
> 6. Worman () says otherwise.

## Desired output

> **1 headlesscite and textcite in footnotes**
>
> Headlesscite here: Worman.
>
> In a footnote.1
>
> With textcite.2
>
> With textcite but no page number.3
>
> **2 with ibid issues thrown in**
>
> Repeated citation.4
>
> Repeated citation with textcite.5
>
> Repeated citation with textcite but no page number.6

where the footnotes are:

> 1. Worman, 1.
> 2. Worman (1) says otherwise.
> 3. Worman says otherwise.
> 4. Ibid., 1.
> 5. Worman (1) says otherwise.
> 6. Worman says otherwise.

Comment: Mhhh, a combination of `\ifsingletitle` and `\headlesscite` is a bit tricky. `\headlesscite` is a `\cite` without author name, and `\ifsingletitle` instructs `\cite` to drop the title if there is only one work by that author. In consequence you end up with nothing being printed. Even if we decide that the desired outcome in this case is for `\headlesscite` not to drop the name, I would probably recommend against using it since the citation labels become a bit inconsistent that way.

Comment: Good point. Do you think it would make sense for me to edit my question to involve only `\textcite`?

Comment: It is your question and hence your decision. I usually prefer questions that revolve around one particular issue and it seems that it would be possible to split the `\headlesscite` and the `\textcite` issue (or drop the `\headlesscite`) entirely, but it may well turn out that a stable solution for one issue solves the other as well.

Comment: The `\headlesscite` one is straight forward (you can add a test for `\ifsingletitle` in the `\headlesscite` command [and friends] and not clear the names if the test is true) . But from my brief look, the `\textcite` issue is much more complicated.

Comment: The complexity is because `\foottextcite` calls `\headlessparenshortcite`. But you can't test if the output of `\headlessparenshortcite` is empty or not from outside `\headlessparenshortcite`. So you always will get parentheses even if it's empty. I don't know where the spurious comma is coming from yet.

Comment: The spurious comma is caused by punctuation in `\postnotewrapper` not being surrounded by `\setunit{…}`. I still don't know how to fix the empty parentheses though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not at all certain that this code will work in all situations, so you should test very carefully.

But perhaps it gives a starting point.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[%
    ibidtracker=true,
    notes, 
    singletitle, 
    short]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% cite:short modified by moewe from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/408916/87678
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\renewbibmacro*{cite:short}{%
  \usebibmacro{allshort+firstcite+xref}%
  \ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR%
    \ifentrytype{inreference}\OR%
    \ifentrytype{reference}\OR%
    \ifentrytype{mvreference}}%
  {\ifthenelse{\iffieldequalstr{entrysubtype}{magazine}\AND\NOT%
      \ifentrytype{periodical}}% Simplify .bib creation
    {\ifuseauthor%
      {\ifboolexpr{%
          not test {\iffieldundef{shortjournal}}%
          and
          ((
          test {\ifcitation}%
          and
          togl {cms@citejtabb}%
          )
          or
          (
          test {\ifbibliography}%
          and
          togl {cms@bibjtabb}%
          ))
        }%
        {\printfield[shortjournal]{shortjournal}\newcunit}%
        {\printfield[journaltitle]{journaltitle}\newcunit}}%
      {}}%
    {\ifentrytype{manual}%
      {\printlist{organization}\isdot\newcunit}%
      {}}}%
  {\ifboolexpr{%
      test {\ifciteidem}%
      and
      not test {\ifbibliography}%
      and
      not test {\iffirstonpage}%
      and
      not togl {cms@noidem}%
      and
      not togl {cms@headlessnote}%
    }%
    {\bibstring[\mkibid]{idem\thefield{gender}}%
      \classicpunct}%
    {\iffieldequalstr{authortype}{anon}%
      {\bibleftbracket\printnames{labelname}%
        \bibrightbracket\classicpunct}%
      {\iffieldequalstr{authortype}{anon?}%
        {\bibleftbracket\printnames{labelname}?%
          \bibrightbracket\classicpunct}%
        {\printnames{labelname}%\usebibmacro{choose+labelname}%
          \isdot\classicpunct}}}}%
  \ifsingletitle
    {}
    {\ifboolexpr{%
       togl {cms@allshort}%
       or
       test {\ifbibliography}%
     }%
     {\printtext[bibhyperref]{%
       \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}}%
     {\printtext[cmshyperlink]{%
       \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}}}}%:\thefield{entrytype}?


% ------------------------------
% Make \headlesscite more robust
% ------------------------------

\DeclareCiteCommand{\headlesscite}
  {\usebibmacro{hlcprenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \toggletrue{cms@headlessnote}%
    \ifsingletitle
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{clear+labelname}%
     \clearname{labelname}}%
    \usebibmacro{cite}%
    \global\toggletrue{cms@noidem}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\headlessparencite}[\mkbibparens]
  {\usebibmacro{hlcprenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \toggletrue{cms@headlessnote}%
    \ifsingletitle
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{clear+labelname}%
     \clearname{labelname}}%
    \usebibmacro{cite}%
    \global\toggletrue{cms@noidem}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\headlessparenshortcite}[\mkbibparens]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \ifboolexpr{%
      togl{cms@firstshort}%
      and
      not test {\iffieldundef{shorthand}}%
    }%
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}%
    {\toggletrue{cms@headlessnote}%
      \toggletrue{cms@shortnote}%
      \togglefalse{cms@fullnote}%
      \ifsingletitle
      {}
      {\clearname{labelname}}%
      \usebibmacro{cite:short}}%
    \global\toggletrue{cms@noidem}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:postnote}}


% ---------------------------------------
% Make \textcite in footnotes more robust
% ---------------------------------------

\renewcommand*{\postnotewrapper}{%
  \iftoggle{cms@modpostnote}%
  {\ifboolexpr{%
      test {\iffieldstart{postnote}{,}}%
      or
      test {\iffieldstart{postnote}{\bibrangessep}}%
    }%
    {\setunit{\addcomma}}% w/ or w/o \addspace?
    {\ifboolexpr{%
        test {\iffieldstart{postnote}{;}}%
        or
        test {\iffieldstart{postnote}{:}}%
        or
        test {\iffieldstart{postnote}{.}}%
      }%
      {}{\setunit{\postnotedelim}}}}%
  {\setunit{\postnotedelim}}}%

\renewcommand{\foottextcite}{%
  \headlessparenshortcite}

\renewcommand{\foottextcites}{%
  \headlessparenshortcites}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\headlessparenshortcite}
  {\ifboolexpr{
     test {\ifsingletitle}
     and
     test {\iffieldundef{postnote}}
   }
   {}
   {\addspace\bibopenparen}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \ifboolexpr{%
      togl{cms@firstshort}%
      and
      not test {\iffieldundef{shorthand}}%
    }%
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}%
    {\toggletrue{cms@headlessnote}%
      \toggletrue{cms@shortnote}%
      \togglefalse{cms@fullnote}%
      \clearname{labelname}%
      \setunit{\addspace}%
      \usebibmacro{cite:short}%
    }%
    \global\toggletrue{cms@noidem}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\ifboolexpr{
     test {\ifsingletitle}
     and
     test {\iffieldundef{postnote}}
   }
   {\usebibmacro{cite:postnote}}
   {\usebibmacro{cite:postnote}%
    \bibcloseparen}}

\begin{document}

\null\vfill

\section{headlesscite and textcite in footnotes}

Headlesscite here: \headlesscite[1]{worman}.

\mancite

In a footnote.\footcite{worman}

\mancite

With textcite.\footnote{\Textcite[1]{worman} says otherwise.}

\mancite

With textcite but no page number.\footnote{\Textcite{worman} says otherwise.}

\section{with ibid issues thrown in}

Repeated citation.\footcite[1]{worman}

Repeated citation with textcite.\footnote{\Textcite[1]{worman} says otherwise.}

Repeated citation with textcite but no page number.\footnote{\Textcite{worman} says otherwise.}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thank you! This works marvelously as far as I can tell. I have tried it on my much larger document as well and have not yet detected any unexpected side-effects (though I should note that I do not typically use any of the more complex compounded versions of `\headlesscite` and `\textcite`).

Comment: @AlexRoberts, you should definitely *not* attempt to pass multiple bib entries to a command or use the multicite variants! They don't work at all. And this is extremely non-trivial to fix (if possible at all).